# getelementsbyID inner dt id values

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbscript

I am extracting data from HTML using Vb Script. This is the HTML code from which am trying to extract the data.

```
<dl id="overview">
<dt id="overview-summary-current-title" class="summary-current" style="display:block">
Current
</dt>
<dd class="summary-current" style="display:block">
<ul class="current">
<li>
   Software Engineer
<span class="at">at </span>
<a class="company-profile-public" href="/company/ABC Systems?trk=ppro_cprof">
<span class="org summary">ABC Systems</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
```

In my previous question, I had asked for a similar doubt. The link is [Excel getElementById extract the span class information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618799/excel-getelementbyid-extract-the-span-class-information).

However, in that case, I wanted to extract the information corresponding to the dl id and it also had span id. In this case, I need to extract the information corresponding to the dt id.

In my VB Script, I tried something like this.

```
Dim openedpage as String
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("overview").getElementById("overview-summary-current-title").innerHTML
```

However, I am getting no output. 
I want the output as **Software Engineer at ABC systems**.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Is this VBScript or VBA? They are different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by `getElementById()` doesn't have a method `.getElementById()`, so the following line fails:

```
.getElementById("overview").getElementById("overview-summary-current-title")
```

If you don't get any output, not even an error message, you probably have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your script. Please don't use that unless you know exactly what you're doing *and* have sensible error handling code in place.

Also, the element with the ID "overview-summary-current-title" is this:

```
<dt id="overview-summary-current-title" class="summary-current" style="display:block">
Current
</dt>
```

So you couldn't possibly extract the text "Software Engineer at ABC systems" from that element.

Try selecting the first `<ul>` tag from the element with the ID "overview", and then use the `innerText` property instead of the `innerHtml` property:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer Application")
ie.Navigate "..."
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

Set e1 = ie.document.getElementById("overview")
Set e2 = e1.getElementsByTagName("ul")(0)
WScript.Echo e2.innerText
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..I was confused on how to extract the correct information. Your help is greatly appreciated.